# How to add a death delay when hitting walls?

Tags: armagetron-advanced

I just started playing Retrocycles and was playing in a few lobbies. In each of the lobbies I played in, they had a feature where if you hit the wall or another player's trail, you would not instantly die but instead be giving a couple of seconds to input a button and save yourself.

Earlier I wanted to play without internet access, and so I started up a local game with bots. When I got in this game I was annoyed to find that you died instantly upon hitting another object. Despite searching through all of the settings I could find, I could not find a way to change this.

How would I go about adding this to my games?

Comment: After discovering that the game is also called Armagetron Advanced, I did some more research and discovered that this has something to do with the rubber settings, but I still don't know how to edit those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing that affects what happens when you hit a wall or another players trail is determined by the rubber settings. There are a very large number of them, but the command you're looking for is `cycle_rubber`.

This command controls how much rubber you have, and therefore how long you can be ramming into a wall before you die. The reason it is so short in your local lobby is because it defaults to 1.

Note this is not a setting in a menu. To edit this you need to open the console by pressing the `~` key, then type in `cycle_rubber x`, where x is a number. I have found 10 to be a good value for allowing you to grind more easily while still allowing the game to end.